# How to report durations of 100+ queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have list of 142 SQL queries in an .sql file.

At the beginning of this file I put `SET profiling = 1;`.

At the end `SHOW PROFILES;`.

I execute it with:

`mysql -u root live_copy < C:/projects/mysqloptimization/mysql_queries.log > output.txt`

But in the output.text file, at the end, it only lists the duration of 15 queries.

1. How can I get it to show me the duration of all 142 queries?
2. Is there a free tool I could use that has a better interface to do this? I use HeidiSQL but it has a limit of giving the output of only 100 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Heidi's tab `Host`, subtab `Variables`, scroll down to the line `profiling_history_size 15` and change its value to 150.

The other way is to launch query like that:

```
SET @@session.profiling_history_size = 150;
```

Comment: When I try to change it to 150, it resets it to 100. I tried this for "session" and "global". I can set it to lower than 100 and it will change, but if I enter anything above 100 it changes it to 100. Are you able to set it to anything above 100?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_profiling_history_size